# Pylance auto import one level too deep (Django)

Tags: python, django, pylance

As described in the title, the pylance auto-import imports one level too deep for Django. It throws an Error "no module named [module_name]". How can I fix it?

My project structure (to the app I want to import from):
Warenwirtschaft/BackEnd/BackEnd/warenwirtschaft

The pylance import:

```
from BackEnd.BackEnd.warenwirtschaft.models import Ingredient
```

The correct import:

```
from BackEnd.warenwirtschaft.models import Ingredient
```

I just don't want to manually type all imports...